# AWQL AdWords API : how to retrieve CampaignStatus?

Tags: api, google-ads-api, awql

I'm using https://www.awql.me to build request and the first one below works, I'm successfully able to retrieve all campaigns with datas from past 7 days :

```
SELECT CampaignId, CampaignName, Clicks, Impressions
FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
DURING LAST_7_DAYS
```

But when I try to add CampaignStatus and/or `ORDER BY` and/or `LIMIT`, I've got the following error message:

```
Underlying errors are 
  Type = 'QueryError.LIMIT_CLAUSE_NOT_SUPPORTED', Trigger = '', FieldPath = ''
```

There is below the request that cause the issue (I also tried to just use `CampaignStatus`,  `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` separately but the same error occured) :

```
SELECT CampaignId, CampaignName, Clicks, Impressions
FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
WHERE CampaignStatus = 'Enabled'
DURING LAST_7_DAYS
ORDER BY Clicks DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

I read that it's not possible to use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` with `CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT`, so how do you guys get around this limitation to retrieve formated datas in the response, at a campaigns level ?
Did you find a way to make the **status works** in your AWQL request ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your `CampaignStatus` filter is that the status value should be `ENABLED` instead of `Enabled`.

As for `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY`, these are indeed not supported in AWQL. You'll have to process the data on your end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-)